# include editform and echo for row id

Tags: php, mysql

What i'm try to do is validate edit form inside an overlay window. It all works fine until I put the form inside the popin.

I'm OK to add row to dbase (vaildated inside popin) and then edit existing records as long as the form is not validated in the popin.

I use includes to show forms inside popin.

The question is how do I echo for row id inside php include?

Should it be somethink like this? Of course it doesn't work.

```
<?php include "editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']"; ?>
```

What would be the correct syntax or should I try a different approach?

Full code for a page is:

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "****");

if (!$con) {    

    die("Error: " . mysql_error());

}
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_3");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/tables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/tables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            @import "/tables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css";


        </style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

          $(document).ready(function(){                
    $('#example').dataTable({                    

        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",                    
        "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],                    
        "bJQueryUI":true

        });           

} );


</script>   

</head>
<body>
<div>
<p><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add new row</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="editmenu/export.php">Export table to xls</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light3').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade3').style.display='block'">Import csv </a></p>
<div id="light" class="white_content">Add a single row to a database<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
<?php include "insertform.html"; ?></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

<div id="light3" class="white_content">Import data from csv file<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade3').style.display='none'">Close</a>
<?php include "editmenu/importcsv.php"; ?></div>
        <div id="fade3" class="black_overlay"></div>



<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th> 
<th>Owner</th> 
<th>Computer Name</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Serial Number</th>
<th>Machine Type</th>
<th>CG-ITO</th> 
<th>Additional Info</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php                    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                       
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Owner']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['Computer_Name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Model']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Serial_Number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Machine_Type']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['CG_ITO']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['Additional_Info']; ?></td>
<td><a class="edit" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade1').style.display='block'">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade2').style.display='block'">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
;?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="light1" class="white_content">Edit single row<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade1').style.display='none'">Close</a>

<?php include "editform.php?id=" . $row['id']; ?></div>
    <div id="fade1" class="black_overlay"></div>

<div id="light2" class="white_content">Delete single row<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade2').style.display='none'">Close</a>
<?php include "deleteval.php"; ?></div>
        <div id="fade2" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you provide us with some code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it that way... The include function requires a path, you need the url wrapper for that to use it, but I don't think it would help you much.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Instead, you can do this:

```
$_GET['id'] = $row['id'];
include "editform.php";
```

And now you can use `$_GET['id']` in that editform.php

Answer (score -1):

it's just php code, so you can use the variable and concatenate it to the filename:

```
<?php include "editform.php?id=" . $row['id']; ?>
```